# FET driving by NPN issue (PWM)

Tags: pwm, driver, npn, fet

I am having a few problems regarding a simple FET PWM driver. I am aware this circuit does not adhere to the best design practice, but I am in a situation where the design cannot be changed.

[image: Circuit schematic]

I have simulated the circuit, which operates how I would expect, but what I am finding in practiceis that once the transistor is loaded by the FET, the output waveform of the transistor distorts as shown in the yellow trace.

This output is then used to drive another FET, this is shown in the blue trace.

[image: Scope traces]

Comment: Welcome! What does each channel on the scope represent?

Comment: Thanks Winny, the yellow channel is at the GATE of the FET. The blue trace can be ignored - this is after the output of another buffer in the chain. Thanks

Comment: If the design can't be changed what do you expect us to help with?

Comment: The values can be changed, I was hoping I may of just missed something.

Comment: It would be good to add the results of your simulation and be explicit as to what behavior you expect, compared to what you're getting.  Without knowing the difference, the question is hard to answer.

Comment: Are R6 and R4 actually in parallel as shown? Why use two resistors?

Comment: Does Q1 collector go to ~0.3 V above ground? If yes, you're at the mercy of your R4||R6 to R5 voltage divider. If not, you're not supplying enough base current.

Comment: Hi Lord, apologies I am trying to work out why the FET is causing the signal to distort in such a strange way. Finbar the resistors R6 and R4 are actually due to the transistor driver and the FET driver being on separate PCB's and are connected by a wire loom.

Comment: What's the Vgs threshold voltage for Q2? How much current are you trying to pass through it?

Comment: Why do you have the 10nF capacitor between gate and source of the MOSFET? You should remove it and you will see some improvement in the waveform. Also the 10k resistor on NPN collector is too much, you should reduce it to no more than 4k7.

Comment: There's wiring carrying a raw gate signal? There are far greater problems than we can help with here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I am at the mercy of the potential divider R6, R5, and R4. The transistor is BC846 and the FET FDD4243. The FDD4243 has a VGS of >3V. The current varies between 0.2-1.5A.

Comment: I have tried by replacing the 10K resistor with a 0R, removing the capacitor, these make some minor improvements. Also the wiring is very short between the two devices. This is a legacy design, not something I have designed.

Comment: Your gate voltage is only about 3.85 V, you need much more for 1.5 A output. Consult the data sheet to see how much more. As a start, remove R6 and C1 and make R5 4k7 as suggested.

Comment: HI Finbarr, I'll give this a go and report back my findings.

Comment: If there are two boards connected with wires, what does "very short" mean as a physical value? Could you insert a third board in the wiring?

Comment: 0.5M. I've replicated the FET and used a function generator to simulate the PWM and this operates as intended. Some instability with the FET driver itself is proving to be the issue.

Comment: @James - Hi, I have reversed your edits which deleted the scope screenshot & schematic from the question. Those are important for the answer to make sense and removing important details from a question isn't done here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The 10nF capacitor between gate and source of the MOSFET is definitely affecting the shape of the signal driving it, and you should remove it. 
The 10k resistor on NPN collector is of a too high resistance, and combined with the 10nF capacitor acts as low-pass filter or a signal integrator, you should reduce it to no more than 4k7. 
I would suggest removing R6, and replacing R4 and R5 with 2k2 (or even 1k) resistors. 
Also, your PWM source could be overloaded or not fully (or not quickly enough) turning the NPN transistor off, so you should try 1k for R2, and reduce the R3 to 10k to help ensure a faster and more complete turn-off. 
Without checking the DC voltages and waveforms on both transistors, it is hard to pinpoint the exact reason for such a badly misshapen waveform.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is misuse of the simulation tool. The mosfet model you're using is for *IC design*. It's not representative of a discrete part. I'm not sure what simulator it is, but it surely has *discrete* mosfets.

It's a classical case of "garbage in, garbage out". As a beginner - and even as a practiced engineer - don't believe in simulation without confirming it on a breadboard/prototype. PCBs are cheap though - why do you think it "cannot be changed now"? It has to be changed.

I guess you went with "simulation" that simulated nothing that could actually be built, and made the PCB for it already, and now it "can't be changed"?

You should have just used an IC gate driver. At least that would have worked at first try if you followed the datasheet and application notes - at least typically.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a legacy design where by the apart from component changes the circuit can not be changed easily. Yes ideally I would of used a driver circuit. The Simulator was to provide a degree of confidence in the circuit. I have replicated the FET part of this and this operates as intended. I will reassess the driver with the modifications mentioned here to see if they have any affect.